# How to set a hardware watchpoint from *within* a process?

Tags: linux, debugging, powerpc, watchpoint

I want like to set a hardware watchpoint on a variable in a process, *from within that same process*. Is that possible? How do I do it?

Using Linux 2.6.32 kernel and a PowerPC A2 processor.